# How should I handle this low quality question which was cross-posted?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, migration, cross-posting

The question is [Minecraft forge mod: Remove a block and place a new block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567906/minecraft-forge-mod-remove-a-block-and-place-a-new-block#comment43562057_27567906)

I tagged it as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) because that's the language used for development in Minecraft, so it *can* be on-topic here if modified properly, but it isn't. Unfortunately a user told them to post to [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) instead and they [did](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197152/minecraft-forge-mod-remove-a-block-and-place-a-new-block), and their [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) indicates that the question is clearly off-topic:

> Please note, however, that site policies *prohibit* questions of the
>   following types:
>
> - Game and Mod Development (try the [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead)

The question however just seems like a *give me da codez*:

> I am currently making a minecraft forge mod. Do anyone know how to
>   first remove a block on specific coordinates, and then place a new
>   block on the same place? Like replacing the old block with a new
>   block.
>
> I will have it in the middle of this code:
>
> ```
> if(player.getCurrentEquippedItem() != null)
>   {
>
>      if(hand.getItem() == Items.dirt)
>      {
>
>      }
>
>   }
> ```
>
> *the Item.dirt is just a test*
>
> So if the player hold a specific item(i use dirt at the moment) and
>   right click on the block, something will happend. Btw i have more code
>   over that code that makes that happend when the player right click on
>   the block.
>
> I've Googled for it and didn't find anything.

I don't think that it should be migrated anywhere at its current state for obvious reasons.

- Is action needed or do we just let the questions get closed and deleted on their own? (As I stated earlier, the question can be modified to be on-topic)
- What do I flag the comment for? I recall a meta discussion about users commenting ("you should post it here instead...") when they shouldn't, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It seems to me that down-vote, preferably with a comment why, is the way to go on SO.  The comment might chastise the person who suggested the cross-post.  On the other site, since it is off-topic, it should be closed as off-topic; they can presumably handle that.